# Open dropdown in header-menu from footer-menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a header menu in which one item gives a big 4-column dropdown menu. To avoid also putting all 18 links in the footer menu I just want to place one link.

When clicking that link in the footermenu I want to scroll the page to the headermenu (succeeded with a simple anchor/name) but I also want to open that dropdown menu. Can that be achieved with the twitter-bootstrap date-properties?

Code for header menu:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="link1">item 1</a></li>
    <li>
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="0" target="#submenu" href="#" name="submenu">item2 <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                        <li><span class="header">HEADER1</span></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="sublink1">subitem1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="sublink1">subitem2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="sublink1">subitem3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                        <li><span class="header">HEADER2</span></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="sublink1">subitem1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="sublink1">subitem2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="sublink1">subitem3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                        <li><span class="header">HEADER3</span></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="sublink1">subitem1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="sublink1">subitem2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="sublink1">subitem3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                        <li><span class="header">HEADER4</span></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="sublink1">subitem1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="sublink1">subitem2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="sublink1">subitem3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="link3">item3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Code for footer menu:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="link1">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="0" target="#submenu" href="#submenu" name="submenu">item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="link3">item3</a></li>
</ul>
```